# Can I get fullscreen in Chrome to work like it does in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

Is there a way for fullscreen in Chrome to work like it does in Firefox?

In Firefox when you're in fullscreen and you hover with the mouse on the top of the screen you see all the menu bars and the bookmarks bar... and it works great.

In chrome you only see: "You've gone full screen, press F11 to exit."

I can't find any extension to make it work like it does in Firefox. Is there one?

Comment: Its not going to work like Firefox. They are seperate programs so their implementation of the same feature ( full screen mode ) is going to be different. A browser extension won't be able to modify this implementation in the way you want.